# Putting Command Block Based Mini Games on Public Server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, server-administration

My friends and I have created our own original Minecraft mini-games over the past year. All our games are powered entirely by command block, not plugins. My friends and I want to share some of our best mini-games with the rest of the world so we want to create a public server. I understand bungee cord and how to run a public server and I will have plugins on the server but I don't know how to incorporate command block based minigames on a public server. I know big servers use original plugins with no command blocks but I do not know any Java to make plugins. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Answer (score 1):

If you are just wanting to use command blocks to make a minigame based server, you really only need a few plugins. Essentials for the basics, WorldEdit, for building, etc... As long as you have command blocks enabled on each individual server on your network you will be fine to import your command block creations. Most common servers use plugins to build minigames but since you built them using command blocks it does not matter.

I would highly suggest using a online host that is good, or perhaps buying a VPS for hosting however as it sounds like what you are planning is going to be pretty resource intensive.

You can not convert command block minigames into a java plugin by the way if that is what you were thinking. Sorry.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Also for future mini-games that we create do you know any good classes that teach plugin coding for complete with little Java experience? Thanks.

Comment: Well I would recommend having a bit of java experiece before starting, but one that was good was a course on udemy, Its called Develop Minecraft Plugins (Java).